# Laravel renaming column database how to avoid renaming all blades

Tags: laravel

I have the following question/problem.
For example i have a user table and i am changing the column name to surname because i want to add lastname. Then i have to edit all my blades $user->name to $user->surname.

Is there a way to do this once?

Change table from

```
$user->name
$user->email
```

Change table to

```
$user->surname
$user->lastname
$user->email
```

Blade:

```
{{$user->name}}
to
{{$user->surname}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Accessor's

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Just say the value of surname will be the value of name and for outside use of the database, your $user will remain with a name

Comment: Nice, if i build an app from scratch and i dont want to use accessors, whats then the best setup?

Comment: It mostly depends on what is your goal, but I like to separate the database structure (the ORM is a representation of your table) from what I sent to the outside

Comment: @Bas If you build from sratch a good way to proceed is to define (for the field that will probably change) in your model this kind of function `public function name(){ return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}` and then in your blade template use `{{ $user->name() }}`. Later if you want to change `firstname` to `surname` in your database, you just have to edit the `name()` function of your model

Comment: @Raccoon I am making ItemController, ItemEntity, ItemModel, ItemRepoInterface and EloquentItemRepo. This will separate it and i only have to change CONST. Im my blade $user->getName()